# Can't open a modal window in angularjs, using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

This is my app.js file:

```
const app = angular.module('CurseTransport', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngMessages',
    'raceModule',


])

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$qProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false)
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/races')
    $stateProvider
        .state('races', {
            url : '/races',
            templateUrl :'views/races.html',
            controller:'racesController'
        })
          .state('racesInsert', {
            url: '/races/insert',
            onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal',
              function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
                $modal

                  // handle modal open
                  .open({
                    template: 'views/racesInsert',
                    windowClass : 'show',
                    controller: ['$scope',
                      function($scope) {
                        // handle after clicking Cancel button
                        $scope.cancel = function() {
                          $scope.$dismiss();
                        };
                        // close modal after clicking OK button
                        $scope.ok = function() {
                          $scope.$close(true);
                        };
                      }
                    ]
                  })

                  // change route after modal result
                  .result.then(function() {
                    // change route after clicking OK button
                    $state.transitionTo('races');
                  }, function() {
                    // change route after clicking Cancel button or clicking background
                    $state.transitionTo('races');
                  });

              }
            ]

          });





}])
```

My view for modal window:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

When i click my button for open the modal window, it is not working. I have no error in my console. I also included       in my scripts.

My modal is located in a different html file.

Comment: i think you have to call the open method .. and a question .. qhy you declare it in the routing? .. is not maybe better to decalre in the racesController and then call it (open) in the init() method of your racesController?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the documentation? https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

You need to use `templateUrl`, not `template` when referencing your modal template, and be sure to include the file extension:

```
$modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'views/racesInsert.html',
  windowClass : 'show',
  ...
```

Only use `template` if you are defining the template inline like this:

```
$modal.open({
  template: '<div class="modal-header"><h1>Modal Heading</h1></div>...',
  windowClass: 'show',
  ...
```

If you are using an inline template as a script, you need to declare the template with a proper script tag. And, do NOT include the outer dialog container:

```
<script id="racesInsert.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

$modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'racesInsert.html',
  windowClass : 'show',
  ...
```

You did not mention which version of Angular UI Bootstrap you are using. The current version uses `$uibModal` not `$modal` as the imported module.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the js function you need to call for modal-

```
$scope.functionName=function(){
 var uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'html page path',
        controller: 'controllerName',
        size: 'lg',
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'app Name',
                    insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before',
                    files: ['js controller file path']
                });
            }]
        }
    });
    uibModalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {

     });
}
```

Call the function functionName when you need to open the popup.

You need to add $uibModal as dependencies in current controller and the model controller should have $uibModalInstance as dependencies.