# Angular 1.6.5 with Webpack load template for uiModal

Tags: html, angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to open a modal window. The background is showing up but there is no modal window.

My code:

```
let template = require('../modal/newModel.html');

let modal = $uibModal.open({
    template,
    controller: 'NewModelCtrl as NewModel',
    windowClass: 'modal-rule-create'
});

modal.result.then((model) => {
    self.list.push(model);
}, (event) => {
    console.log('Close modal window:', event);
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
 {
     test: /\.html$/,
     use: 'html-loader'
 }
```

Why is that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: Not one is all pure

Comment: Can you set your path inside templateUrl:''../modal/newModel.html' and make sure does that template gets loaded

Comment: I use the webpack html-loader for html files, in chrome devtools I'll output the value of the variable, it's got to be using inline template, but it does not work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2VbUG/1/ like mine

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the fiddle by changing the structure of the div's and added jquery references [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjudxjc7/3/)

In your case make sure you have added Jquery before bootstrap.js, try to see the version mismatch or try to change -

```
let modal = $uibModal.open({ 
    templateUrl = '../modal/newModel.html',
    controller: 'NewModelCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'NewModel',
    windowClass: 'modal-rule-create'
});
```

You can refer to this questions as they have similar problem like yours -

[Can't open a modal window in angularjs, using bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468695/cant-open-a-modal-window-in-angularjs-using-bootstrap)

[ui.bootstrap modal loading html but not showing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952510/ui-bootstrap-modal-loading-html-but-not-showing-anything)

Answer (score 0):

Would be useful if you setup a plunker. Anyway if you want to use an alias for your controller the code should be like:

```
let modal = $uibModal.open({ 
  template,
  controller: 'NewModelCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'NewModel',
  windowClass: 'modal-rule-create'
});
```

Maybe that's messing your modal.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It did not help

Answer (score 0):

Here the html code, window rendering did not happen

```
<div uib-modal-window="modal-window" class="modal fade ng-scope ng-isolate-scope in" role="dialog" index="0" animate="animate" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + $$topModalIndex*10, display: 'block'}" tabindex="-1" uib-modal-animation-class="fade" modal-in-class="in" modal-animation="true" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a problem.

Maybe someone will be useful:

Angular 1.6.5
Angular-ui-bootstrap 2.5.0

There is the following code:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push([
    '$injector',
    function ($injector) {
        return $injector.get('AuthInterceptor');
    }
]);
```

And:

```
.factory('AuthInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, AUTH_EVENTS, Filters) 
{
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            let regEx = /.+\.html$/;
            let template = regEx.test(config.url);

            if (!template) {
                if (config.url !== "/uaa/oauth/token" && 
            Filters.get('token')) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + 
            Filters.get('token');
                }
            }

            return config;
        },
        response: function (response) {
            let regEx = new RegExp('.+\.html$');
            let template = regEx.test(response.config.url);
            let data;

            if (!template) {
                if (response.status && response.status !== 200) {
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }

                data = response.data || response;
                return $q.resolve(data);
            }

            return response;
        },
        responseError: function (response) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast({
                401: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated,
                403: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized,
                419: AUTH_EVENTS.sessionTimeout,
                440: AUTH_EVENTS.sessionTimeout,
                500: 'bad-request'
            }[response.status], response);
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
})
```

In old version of my code, angular try return template cache of modal window. But in my code after processing it was not returned.